# Error "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

Below is the HTML code. I am trying to create editor using ace js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script>
    window.onload = function what() {
      var a = document.getElementById("abc");
      a.innerHTML = 'hi';
    };
  </script>
  <title>ACE in Action</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #editor {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="editor">
    <span id="abc">Class </span>{ public void add(int a, int b){ int sum=a+b; } }
  </div>
  <script src="http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ext-language_tools.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ClassData.json"></script>
  <script>
    var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/java");
    editor.setOptions({
      enableBasicAutocompletion: true
      // enableLiveAutocompletion: true
    });
    var staticWordCompleter = {
      getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
        var wordList = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "arpit", "abhishek"];
        callback(null, wordList.map(function(word) {
          return {
            caption: word,
            value: word,
            meta: "class"
          };
        }));

      }
    }

    langTools.addCompleter(staticWordCompleter);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Error:

> Error "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null".

I am trying to create an online editor using Ace JS with features like auto-import of package when any object is created and add custom name of class. For this, I added a 'p' tag next to Class so that I can insert some text in that line but it is not able to detect the id named 'abc'.

Comment: move that script to the `<body/>`

Comment: Please, fix this: `<body >`.

Comment: tried that as well.. didnt work

Comment: @Pankwood There's nothing wrong with `<body >`; it's perfectly valid HTML.

Comment: I am willing to be that the editor code changes it so it does not work.... So look at what the editor does to your element.... Or rethink what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the ACE editor you are using does not accept HTML within the textfield. Opening the Developer Tools and Inspecting the content reveals that the ACE editor removed the `span` with id `abc`, that's why you get a null pointer trying to access the not existing element.

The beginning of the Text has been modified by the editor to look like `<span class="ace_support ace_function">Class</span>`when viewed in developer tools.